# FLEX, Actionscript: how can I invoke a CustomEvent?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I've created a custom MouseEvent in Flex:

```
package {

    import flash.events.MouseEvent; 
    public class CustomMouseEvent extends MouseEvent {

        public var tags:Array = new Array();    
        public function CustomMouseEvent(type:String, tags:Array) {
            super(type, true);
            this.tags = tags;
        }
    }
   }
```

Now I would like to understand how to pass the parameter tags from both Actionscript and MXML:

From actionscript I'm trying something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
newTag.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dispatchEvent(new CustomMouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,[newTag.name])));
```

From MXML i'm doing this and it doesn't work as well:

```
<mx:LinkButton click="dispatchEvent(new CustomMouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, bookmarksRepeater.currentItem.tags))" />
```

thanks

Comment: Why do you make your class extend MouseEvent? I'd think its lots easier and also more clear if you create a class that extends Event. (And I'm guessing you'll be better of if you define your own event name and don't use the MOUSE_UP in that case)

Comment: ok you right, i'm extending Event now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping the callback code in a function:

```
newTag.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, function(e:MouseEvent):void {
    dispatchEvent(new CustomMouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, [e.currentTarget.name]));
});
```

I think the issue with the MXML code is that you are using a repeater and trying to get the `currentItem` after the repeating has finished. Try this instead:

```
<mx:LinkButton click="dispatchEvent(new CustomMouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, event.currentTarget.getRepeaterItem().tags))" />
```

Hope that helps.

**Update**

Since you are creating the `newTag` object in a loop, you'll get better memory usage by just using a named function as the event listener.

```
newTag.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onTagClick);

...

protected function onTagClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    dispatchEvent(new CustomMouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, [e.currentTarget.name]));
}
```

That way you only create one event listener, rather than `n` listeners that do that exact same thing.

Comment: yeah.. I have the same problem with newTag. newTag is created in a for loop, so I newTag.name is just the name of the last tag I've added (when I trigger the event, run-time). So what's the solution ?

Comment: Just updated my answer to show using the `currentTarget` of the event to get the correct `newTag` object. Does that work?

Answer (score 2):

also, you may be getting TypeErrors for not having overridden the clone method. You should fix that now, before you run into it later.

greetz
back2dos

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing type to something other than a type that is currently being used.  Something like CustomMouseEvent.MY_CUSTOM_MOUSE and then catch that to see if this works.  Not sure if using the same Type name as a standard type is a good technique.